# How to make ajax call in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

In yii version 1.14 we used

> CHtml::ajaxlink

for ajax call what about in yii2?

Comment: Is csrf token required in the following answers?

Comment: [Here](http://www.yiiplayground.com/yii2/web/index.php?r=ajax/index) is an example

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can make an ajax link like

```
 Html::a('Your Link name','controller/action', [
'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Close'),
    'onclick'=>"$('#close').dialog('open');//for jui dialog in my page
     $.ajax({
    type     :'POST',
    cache    : false,
    url  : 'controller/action',
    success  : function(response) {
        $('#close').html(response);
    }
    });return false;",
                ]);
```

Comment: Thanks Dancy G B and NinjaCat for your answer, but I am getting an internal server error when using jQuery.ajax({     url: '../product/openfancybox',
data: {id: quan},
success: function(data) {
alert(data);
}
});

Answer (score 9):

From: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/665/overcoming-removal-of-client-helpers-e-g-ajaxlink-and-clientscript-in-yii-2-0/

> You can easily create and combine all such client helpers for your
>   need into separate JS files. Use the new AssetBundle and AssetManager
>   functionality with the View object in Yii2, to manage these assets and
>   how they are loaded.
>
> Alternatively, inline assets (JS/CSS) can be registered at runtime
>   from within the View. For example you can clearly simulate the
>   ajaxLink feature using a inline javascript. Its however recommended if
>   you can merge where possible, client code (JS/CSS) into separate
>   JS/CSS files and loaded through the AssetBundle. Note there is no more
>   need of a CClientScript anymore:

```
$script = <<< JS
$('#el').on('click', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
       url: '/path/to/action',
       data: {id: '<id>', 'other': '<other>'},
       success: function(data) {
           // process data
       }
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, $position);
// where $position can be View::POS_READY (the default), 
// or View::POS_HEAD, View::POS_BEGIN, View::POS_END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get( "' . Url::toRoute('controller/action') . '", { item: $("#idoffield").val()} ) /* to send the parameter to controller*/
                        .done(function( data )
                            {
                                 $( "#lists" ).html( data );
                                    })
```

and give lists id for  div

```
<div id="lists"></div>
```

for more visit https://youtu.be/it5oNLDNU44

Answer (score -3):

```
<?=yii\helpers\Url::toRoute("site/signup")?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Well it doesn't answer the question, at all.