# Sending ajax request in yii2: Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: ajax, yii2

This is my script:

```
$.post('index.php?r=site/filterbyprice',{
        price_range:values,
        _csrf : $("#csrftoken").val()
        }
        ,function(r){
            console.log(r);
            if(r==""){
                $("#all-ads").html('<div class="error-page"></div>');
            }
            else{
                $("#all-ads").html(r);  
            }
    });
```

controller code:

```
public function actioAbc(){
    echo 'inside abc';
}
```

I am facing the following error:  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://mandigoods.com/frontend/web/index.php?r=site/abc. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199595/how-to-make-ajax-call-in-yii2

Answer (score 0):

Could be a header config problem. First, try to generate your url with:

```
$url = yii\helpers\Url::to(['site/filterbyprice']);
```

and including it into your view like this:

```
$this->registerJs(<<<JS

$.post('{$url}',{...});

JS;
);
```

excluding the `_csrf : $("#csrftoken").val()` that should be handled by Yii2 automatically.

Then, I'd check your server config (Apache / Nginx) regarding your headers, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665056/angularjs-cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-readi) for the configuration.